#  ProGuard: can't find referenced class (to R.java)

Tags: android, proguard, android-library

I have an Android app that references to a library Android project. That setup basically works fine (as debug release in Eclipse). However, when I try to export a signed release apk of the main app, with ProGuard enabled in project.properties, export fails.

Problem seems to be that ProGuard can't find the resource class R.java of the referenced library project, because all warnings complain about R$string, R$layout, etc. of that library project.

I am using Android's default proguard.cfg file.
Do I need any changes in that case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you found an answer, you should post it as an answer to your question, rather than editing the question.  It'll be clearer and more helpful if a future visitor comes along with the same issue. I'd vote up both if you do so as it's a lot more helpful for future users.

Comment: done, wrote my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I indeed had to include the path to the library project source folder with the -libraryjars switch in the proguard.cfg file.